# Online facsimile of the original Cours de linguistique générale

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I am looking for the original 1916 edition of Ferdinand de Saussure's *Cours de linguistique générale*.  The book must be out of copyright by now; does there exist an online scan or similar facsimile that preserves the original page numbering?  Failing that, are there any modern reprints of the first edition (again, preserving the original page numbering)?

Comment: It is (apparently) still protected by copyright, until the end of the year. The last surviving author appears to be Charles Bally, died 1946, so at the end of 70 years from then, that version is out of copyright.

Comment: That is to say, he died in 1947...